# Leaflet JS iconUrl & Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am using laravel.

In my blade file I have the following code:

```
<div
    id="mapid"
    class="h-screen w-full z-0"
></div >

@push('head-scripts')
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"integrity="sha512 ... </script>
@endpush


@push('scripts')

    <script>
    //Making map and tiles

    const mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([0, 0], 3);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
        tileSize: 512,
        zoomOffset: -1,
        accessToken: 'pkkagdgfsecretblablabdfgkjfdökhdfjgfag'
    }).addTo(mymap);

    // making a marker with an icon

    const myIcon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-green.png',
        iconSize: [50, 32], // size of the icon
        iconAnchor: [22, 16], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location

    });

    const marker = L.marker([0, 0, {icon: myIcon}]).addTo(mymap);

    marker.setLatLng([50, 20]);

</script >

@endpush
```

I want to paste an alternative icon into

iconUrl: ,

I tried

```
iconUrl: 'http://somelink/some.png',
iconUrl: 'https://somelink/some.png',
iconUrl: './images/some.png',
iconUrl: '/images/some.png',
iconUrl: '/svg/some.png',
iconUrl: './svg/some.png',
iconUrl: {{ asset('/images/some.png') }},
iconUrl: {{ asset('./images/some.png') }},
iconUrl: {{ asset('./svg/some.png') }},
iconUrl: url{{ asset('/images/some.png') }},
iconUrl: '../../public/some.png',
```

How can I reference a *.png or anyother format inside a  tag inside a laravel blade component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your image in your "/public" folder and set inside your javascript
`iconUrl: '{{ URL::asset('/some.png') }}'`

Hope it helps :)